# Play 2.5 with Akka - could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm attempting to test out Akka with Play 2.5 and I'm running into a compile error I can't seem to get around.

I'm following this page from the Play docs:
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka

Here is the full code:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import controllers.HelloActor.SayHello
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask

@Singleton
class Application @Inject()(system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

  implicit val timeout = 5.seconds

  val helloActor = system.actorOf(HelloActor.props, "hello-actor")

  def sayHello(name: String) = Action.async {
    (helloActor ? SayHello(name)).mapTo[String].map { message =>
      Ok(message)
    }
  }
}

import akka.actor._

object HelloActor {
  def props = Props[HelloActor]

  case class SayHello(name: String)

}

class HelloActor extends Actor {
  import HelloActor._

  def receive = {
    case SayHello(name: String) =>
      sender() ! "Hello, " + name
  }
}
```

My route looks like:

```
GET     /:name                      controllers.Application.sayHello(name: String)
```

And, finally, my build.sbt:

```
name := "AkkaTest"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `akkatest` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , cache , ws   , specs2 % Test )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )  

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

When I attempt to run this, I get the following compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout
```

I've tried moving around the timeout to no avail.  Does anyone have an idea what might cause this compilation error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You getting this error because the *ask pattern* requires an implicit timeout for asking (it will complete future with `TimeoutException` if no answer was received for this time). So all you need is to create an implicit local value in `sayHello` method like this:

```
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

// ...

  def sayHello(name: String) = Action.async {
    implicit val timeout: Timeout = Duration.Infinite
    (helloActor ? SayHello(name)).mapTo[String].map { message =>
      Ok(message)
    }
  }
```

Instead of specifying infinite timeout you can specifiy a finite one with following syntax:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.util.Timeout

implicit val duration: Timeout = 20 seconds
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!  I can't believe I missed that - works perfectly now.

Comment: For the record the 2.5 docs have the line as follows `implicit val timeout = 5.seconds` which fails to work (with the same above error) until you explicitly add the TYPE as follows: `implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds`

Comment: As of akka 2.5.8 `Duration.Inf` cannot be used for `Timeout`, as it expects finite duration.

Answer (score 0):

When testing 'ask', you will need two implicits: one for timeout, and another for executionContext (which is a kind of thread pool). Both are needed, since, ask actually returns a future, so, it needs a thread pool to run from, and there has to be a timeout since one is not expected to wait on a future forever. Code is below.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

implicit val timeout: Timeout = 30 seconds

(actor ? message).mapTo[<whatever is your type of return>)].map(x => Ok /* or do any validation */)
```